# RSA Private Exponent

Tags: rsa, public-key

Is it possible to calculate the private exponent when only the RSA public key (e;N) = (9292162750094637473537; 13029506445953503759481) is given?

Comment: That would only be possible for definitions of RSA that uniquely define _the_ private exponent, such as [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=62); not for definitions of RSA that allow several private exponents, such as [PKCS#1](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/pkcs/files/h11300-wp-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard.pdf#page=7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since $N=p
\times q$, so we have $13029506445953503759481 = 109217267039×119298960679$,
also the private and public exponent $e$ and $d$ are related by the equation $ed\equiv1\text{ mod }\phi(N)\equiv1\text{ mod }((109217267039-1)×(119298960679-1)) $.
You should then be able to find $d$, the private exponent.

Comment: How were you able to find the primes?

Comment: @ArsalanAmjid probably by handing the modulus to a factoring tool?

Comment: @Arsalan [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factors+of+13029506445953503759481) factored it in about 3 seconds.  Note that in real life, N (and hence p and q) would be much, much larger...

Comment: Yes, @Dan is right, now the standard for the modulus $N$ is at least $1024$ bits.